# Wicked_pdf too few arguments in demo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I'm trying to get wicked_pdf working for the first time as a project in learning RoR, but i've run into an issue.

When I try to run any of the demo's I've read around the place using the `format.pdf do` command, I get the error "`Too few arguments`" with highlighting on the `format.pdf do` line.

This is the code:

```
  def show
    format.pdf do
      render :pdf => "file_name", :template => 'certificates/show.pdf.erb'
    end
  end
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this.. I had same problem.

```
def show
    #format.pdf do
      render :pdf => "file_name", :template => 'certificates/show.pdf.erb'
    #end
  end
```

I believe you have `gems` **'wkhtmltopdf-binary'** and **'wicked_pdf'** installed

Comment: Awesome, that worked. You are right, I have the wkhtmltopdf-binary and wicked_pdf gems installed. Do you know why the `format.pdf do` isn't actually working?

Answer (score 1):

enclose

> ```
>  format.pdf do
>       render :pdf => "file_name", :template => 'certificates/show.pdf.erb'
>     end
> ```

in a `respond_to` block, something like:

> ```
> respond_to do |format|
>    format.pdf do
>       render :pdf => "file_name", :template => 'certificates/show.pdf.erb'
>     end
> end
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggested code and now I get the error `ActionController::UnknownFormat`

Answer (score 0):

Quick way

Install the following gems

```
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

Use *which wkhtmltopdf* and identify the path

Create a symbolic link

```
ln -s path_from_which /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

Edit/Create wicked initializers

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  #:wkhtmltopdf => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
  #:layout => "pdf.html",
  :exe_path => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
}
```

In your controller find your action and

```
def show
  render pdf: "file_name"   # Excluding ".pdf" extension.
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add :layout

```
render :pdf => "notifications",
        :layout => 'layouts/pdf/layout.html.erb',
        :template => 'notification_compulsories/show.pdf.erb'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and the solution for me was to include the `html` format in the `respond_to` block. This

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.pdf  { render pdf: "ticket_report" }
end
```

became this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :index }
  format.pdf  { render pdf: "report" }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. You can add a `defaults` hash to the route and specify the format.

`get "/pdf_name.pdf" => "your_controller#action", as: :pdf_route, defaults: { format: :pdf }`