# whkpdf giving ActionController::UnknownFormat error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I am trying to integrate wicked_pdf into my rails 4 application. How ever I am having UnknownFormat error.

In the gem file I have added

```
  gem 'wicked_pdf'
```

In my students controller I have show method define like below:

```
   controllers/students_controllers

   respond_to :html, :js, :pdf

   def show
     @student = Student.find(params[:id])
     respond_to do |format|
       format.pdf do
         render :pdf => "students",:template => "students/show_pdf"
       end
   end
```

Then I have show_pdf.pdf.erb template in my students viewsfolder.
How ever I have added Wicked_pdf engin path at

```
initializers/wicked_paf.rb 

WickedPdf.config = {
   :exe_path => '/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
}
```

I have also added mime type for pdf at initilizers/mime_type.rb

```
  initializers/mime_type.rb

  Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
```

But there is no luck. I got the unknownformat error.

```
  ActionController::UnknownFormat at /students/1
  ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

I don't know the reason of this error. Please help me to find out the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume it's because you're not going to /students/1.pdf

Comment: This must solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22877724/wicked-pdf-too-few-arguments-in-demo/22878206#22878206

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You don't have to add "pdf" as a new mime_type in Rails 4 (it's already there).
2. There is a typo in your file_path: "initializers/wicked_paf.rb" instead of "initializers/wicked_pdf.rb".
3. Try to change the #show in controller this way:

   ```
   def show
       respond_to do |format|
         format.html
         format.pdf do
           render :pdf => "students"
         end
       end
   end
   ```

Of course you'll need to make the proper view for it in your 'app/views/students/show.html.erb'.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have the `format: 'pdf'` in your link_to:

```
link_to 'My PDF', print_pdf_path, format: 'pdf'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add .pdf to your endpoint:
Example: api/reports/1.pdf